# Print array values from select syntax in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a database which have 4 records in it. And I want to display the record details of which having reg_no = "IT17052498" (I'm already having that record in the db). But it gives and error like

"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\labsheet 10\addcomment.php on line 85"

Database connection are as followed name(db_connect.php)

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$mysql_db = "iwt";

$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$mysql_db);
if(!$connection)
{
die("Error : ".mysqli_error($connection));
}

else
{
echo "Successfully Connected!<br>";
}
?>
```

Here is my php code..

```
<html>

<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Registration Number</th>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Comment on ITA</th>
</tr>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btn_search"]))
$srch = $_POST["search"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM  library_comment WHERE regNo = $srch";

$exst = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exst))
{

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['regNo'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['comment'] ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}

?>


</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd tag this with php also

Comment: Cool SQL injection. (And HTML injection from the DB.) :-(

Comment: That file doesn't even have 85 lines.

Comment: `$srch = $_POST["btn_search"];` is a good start

Comment: @danronmoon Are you sure about that? `btn_search` sounds like it's the form submit button.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Got confused about the logic

Comment: @melpomene According to my code I have previous codes like Insert, Update, Delete etc. Final one is the above code. And the problem occured with this code. Line 85 means sense in the "while loop"...

Comment: If regNo is a string, then it needs to be quoted as a string, or bound as a string to a prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

I don't even use PHP, but the error message says the problem is in the first argument in the call to `mysqli_fetch_array()`:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($exst)
```

Specifically, `$exst` is supposed to be a `mysqli_result` object, but it's actually a `boolean` (either `true` or `false`).

`$exst` comes from this line:

```
$exst = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

http://php.net/mysqli_query says:

> Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful *SELECT*, *SHOW*, *DESCRIBE* or *EXPLAIN* queries `mysqli_query()` will return a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object.

In other words, `mysqli_query` is failing and returning `false`, and your code doesn't check for errors, it just assumes everything is OK. This is the immediate source of your problem.

On another note, the documentation also says

> Data inside the query should be [properly escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Your code doesn't escape anything. This might be why the query fails.